# retrieve and insert image in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, image, insert

I am inserting and displaying various data with images.I am working on a restyrant website where I am storing and displaying the items along with their images.I have created two tables named 
food(id[P.K],name,price,image,cat_id[F.K]) 
category(cat_id[P.K],cat_name)
 1-my task is to display the all categories in navigation bar.
 2-when I click on the category it should display the food that comes under the category
 3-insert and update the information

1-My first task was to display the food items onClicking the category.here is the code and it is working perfectly

```
<?php  

$category=mysql_query("Select * from category",$connection);

while($category_name=mysql_fetch_array($category)) {

      $category_name['cat_name'];

      echo  "<li><br><a href=\"show.php?category=". urlencode($category_name["cat_id"]) . "\">{$category_name["cat_name"]}</a></li>" . "<br />";   

}

      if(isset($_GET['category']))

{

           $query="Select * from food where cat_id={$_GET['category']} ";

           $result=mysql_query($query,$connection);


     while($food_name=mysql_fetch_array($result))

             {


     echo $food_name["food_name"]. " Price is " . $food_name["food_price"];
```

it is displaying the data from the food table and this is place where I have to      write the code in order to display images.

```
        }

 }
```

the task of storing the images in database is working perfectly.

Comment: Please stop duplicating questions only because you are not confident with the answers so far. [Dupe1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11541357/367456) [Dupe2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555424/retrieve-and-displaying-images-in-php-using-mysql)

Comment: I am new to this site and I had to add the additional code to my exixsting question.I did not see the edit option in that that's y I posted it again with the revised code

Comment: If you are new here, [the FAQ page](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) might be a good place to start.

Comment: your code is difficult to read, please use a standard indentation...

Answer (score 2):

Storing and retrieving images in a database is really slow and difficult. You may give images a unique id (like timestamp) and save them into your `images` folder or you may create a special folder for this. Then, make an extra column in your table and save the id in corresponding rows. You may retrieve images using the example below;

```
echo '<img src="images/'.$imageid.'.jpg">';
```

Hope this helps...`:)`

Comment: I have uploaded the insertion of image code plz have a look at it and tell me where I have to use the your code

Answer (score 1):

Storing images in database is not a good practise. In this case, you have to use `<img>` tag to retrieve those images

Comment: Check [this!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: the code of inserting the image in databse here is the form

 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="insert.php" >

<p>Name:<input type="text" name="food_name"  id="food_name"/>
<p>Price:<input type="text" name="food_price"  id="food_price"/>
<input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400" type="hidden">
<input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
}